# In Coldfusion, some Arabic characters not displaying in PDF

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdocument

Some of the Arabic characters are not displaying in PDF.
Do I need to add any font in ColdFusion Administrator
I gave **المينــاء** as input inside the tag CFDOCUMENT to show in PDF format.

In PDF, the output I am getting is  **اينــاء** instead of **المينــاء**.

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fontembed` attribute of `cfdocument` and set it to `true` to embed the specified fonts in the output. You need to wrap your text inside `span` and specify the suitable `font-family` (font-family that displays your text better as required) in its `style` attribute. As @bibin suggested use `Arial Unicode MS` as the `font-family`.
Like this:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" overwrite="true" fontembed="true">
    <span style="font-size:20pt;font-family:Arial Unicode MS;">
        المينــاء
    </span>
</cfdocument>
```

Another `font-family` able to display the text is `Traditional Arabic`.
You can install other more accurate font in CF Admin if you find one, and use it as a font family.

Update:

In my case the font is already available in CF Admin. So here `fontEmbed` is not really needed. It is helpful in case the font is not available in CF Admin and we want to use the font directly from CF page.

Answer (score 2):

got to c:/ drive >> windows folder >> fonts

check sure **arial unicode ms** is there if not there please add arial unicode ms.ttf

and inside CFML/HTML code please use like this  style="font-family:arial unicode ms    بيالتلان